# Documentation generator tool for multiple languages

Tags: java, python, ruby, bash, documentation-generator

I have project that written with Ruby, Java, Python and Bash and currently I'm searching for single documentation tool that can be used to generate web pages, like `Sphinx-doc` does
Precondition is not to add anything to code except meta-comments(like in `Sphinx-doc` or `rdoc`)

So far I've found nothing suitable. Can you advice something for my case?

Answer (score 1):

Sphinx-doc itself:

- comes with support for Python and C/++,
- it has a domain for Ruby in the [contrib area](https://bitbucket.org/birkenfeld/sphinx-contrib/) or [here](https://bitbucket.org/birkenfeld/sphinx-contrib),
- there is a Java domain, [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/javasphinx/), and
- can be extended for other language parsing, to add bash to the list if you cannot find an extension should be trivial.